# Event is not fired on dynamic li elements

Tags: jquery

On load of the page, I'm creating horizontal tabs in Jquery using:

```
function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
    var categoryArr = JSON.parse(categories);
    var htmlbuild = $('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.categories.length; i++) {
          var name = categoryArr.categories[i].name;
          htmlbuild.append('<li id= "'+name+'" class="active">'+name+'</a></li>');
     }
       htmlbuild.append('</ul>');
       $("#menuInner").append(htmlbuild);
}
```

my HTML code:

```
 <body>
    <section class="menuWrap">
        <div id = "menuInner" class="menuInner"> 
        </div>
    </section>
 </body>
```

I'm trying to register with the click event of li selected this way, but this is not getting fire up.

I need to keep this  outside the **Jquery** ready() function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     createhorizontaltab(categories)
}

$("#menuInner li ").click(function(){
}
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this,

```
$(document).on( "click", "#menuInner li", function() {
  //
});
```

**[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** - Event delegation

Or

```
$(document).delegate( "#menuInner li", "click", function() {
 //
});
```

**[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** - Attaches a handler to one or more events for elements specified in the selector, now or in the **future**.

And you were appending elements dynamically.

Comment: Thank you , Working fine , or else i could have googled for  the whole day , Jquery is huge .

Comment: @Kiran ***Jquery is huge***, not really, I just see jQuery's ***plugins*** are huge.

Comment: would stick with using `on()` since internally `delegate` will use `on()` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add event handler when on page load, but the `li` is not exist on page that time.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to

So, you must use Event delegation

> The event is dispatched to its target  EventTarget and any event
>   listeners found there are triggered. Bubbling events will then trigger
>   any additional event listeners found by following the EventTarget's
>   parent chain upward, checking for any event listeners registered on
>   each successive EventTarget. This upward propagation will continue up
>   to and including the Document.

```
$(document).on( "click", "#menuInner li", function() {
  // your code
});
```