# JQuery .click() not working on appended <tr> from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table where the table rows are being .appended through my ajax return.

The Ajax call/return

```
$("#searchButton").click(function(){
    var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
    var data = {
      action: 'mysearch',
      post_lastName: lastName
    };
    $.post(
        the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        data,
        function(response)
        {
            $("#searchResults").append(response);
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

HTML file where the search results appear

```
<div class="retained intake_content">
        <table id="searchResults" style="width:80%">

        </table>
</div>
        <style>
            #searchResults tr:hover {
                background-color: orange;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
```

And my php for retrieving the info from SQL and echoing the created table row.

```
while($row = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $firstName = $row['first_name'];
        $lastName = $row['last_name'];
        $id = $row['id'];

        echo '<tr><td>' . $firstName .'</td><td>' . $lastName . '</td><td>' . $id .'</td><td><button type="button" id="personid" name="rowId" value="' . $id  . '"> View</button></td></tr>';
    }
```

My test to see if the button was clicked.

```
$("#personid").click(function(){

    //var id =$(this).val();
    console.log("Clicked");
    alert('Row has been clicked');
});
```

I added a button with the id of rowsid with the intention of using JQuery .click() event to send the ID to another ajax call to retrieve more detailed information. The problem is I can not get the JQuery .click() to alert at all. I then tried if console.log would work and it did not.

So I am guessing .append() has alot to do with this issue or the way I echoed the table? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW this is in a wordpress plugin...

Comment: Use event delegation. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23932472/3639582

Comment: @ShaunakD Worked like a charm! But I don't see why your method works while I failed. I'll take a look at the API but Im guessing since I added the table row dynamically I needed to select the document again? $(document).on();

Comment: The problem is everytime you append a row the ID is getting repeated. Duplicate IDs are invalid html. Try using classes.

Comment: @ShaunakD Just wanted to give an update. I used something like $(document).on("click", "#personid", function(){

        var personid =$(this).val(); }                      And it works fine with any number of rows. Thanks SHAUNAKD !!!! I will try and accept the most clear answer now that I understand how its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
        <title>Dialog</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('document').ready(function(){   
                $('#search').click(function(){
                    $.get( 'table.php' ,function(data) {
                        $('#tb').append(data);
                    });
                    return false;
                });

                $('#tb').on('click','tr',function(){
                    alert($(this).attr('personID'));
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
           table,tr,td{ border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse;}
        </style>
        <table id="tb">

        </table>
        <a href="#" id="search">Search</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo '<tr personID="1"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>';
echo '<tr personID="2"><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>';
?>
```

Comment: Not the exact method I used to get this to work, But the answer is laid out perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`personid` conflict I think, there are more than one button what's id property is 'personid'.
Try 

`$( "#searchResults tr td button[name='rowId']" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ));
});`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the class attribute in your buttons because not correct repeat ids in an HTML document.

Try this:

```
<table><tr><td>some</td><td><button class='btn' value='1'></button></td></tr></table>

<script>
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
$("#personid").live('click', function(){
    //var id =$(this).val();
    console.log("Clicked");
    alert('Row has been clicked');
});
```

Comment: live() is a deprecated function in jQuery since 1.7+ . Use the on() function http://api.jquery.com/live/