# Populating data into table using JQuery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to populate a database result in an HTML table. When the `<a class="editUsers">` is clicked a box should pop up to show data from an Ajax call.

**This should be shown:**

```
<table id="userInfo">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <td>User</td>
            <td>Mail</td>
            <td>Admin Access</td>
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane Doe</td>
        <td>janedoe@islost.com</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
$(".editUsers").click(function(){
    $("#userInfo").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".exitUsrMgmt").fadeIn(1000); //This is the close button for that popup

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "includes/getUserData.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                   
            ("#userInfo").html(response);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
<?php
  include_once('config.php');

  //Create PDO Object
  $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
  //Set Error Handling for PDO
  $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  //Query
  $sql = "SELECT name, email, admin FROM user_admin";

  //Prepare Statement
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row[2].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: For starters, `("#userInfo").html(response);` is missing a `$`. Should be `$("#userInfo").html(response);`

Comment: Wow. I could hit myself with a brick right now. I looked at that code for like 30 minutes and didn't find that silly mistake. Everything works now. Thanks :)

Comment: May this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770664/jquery-click-not-working-on-appended-tr-from-ajax/30771297#30771297

Answer (score 1):

Problem was fixed. I did a silly mistake and forgot to include a `$`. Thanks to Paul Roub for the answer, I quote:

> For starters, `("#userInfo").html(response);` is missing a `$`. Should be
>   `$("#userInfo").html(response);` – Paul Roub 8 mins ago